# Почему ответ разный из-за одной скобки

Tags: python

У меня есть функция которая складывает вектора:

```
    def vector_sum(vectors):
    '''Суммируем все соответствующие элементы'''
    assert vectors, 'Векторы не предоставлены'

    #Проверить, что векторы имеют одинаковый размер
    num_elements = len(vectors[0])
    assert all(len(v) == num_elements for v in vectors), 'Векторы должны иметь одинаковую длину'

    return [sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors)
                for i in range(num_elements)] # Здесь скобка после vectors

print(vector_sum([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

В итоге ответ таков: [5, 7, 9]

Но в коде, где скобка стоит чуть дальше ответ другой:

```
    def vector_sum(vectors):
    '''Суммируем все соответствующие элементы'''
    assert vectors, 'Векторы не предоставлены'

    #Проверить, что векторы имеют одинаковый размер
    num_elements = len(vectors[0])
    assert all(len(v) == num_elements for v in vectors), 'Векторы должны иметь одинаковую длину'

    return [sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors
                for i in range(num_elements))] # Здесь скобка после num_elements

print(vector_sum([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

Вывод: [21]

Объясните пожалуйста)))

Comment: Потому что есть разница - просуммировать элементы в столбцах или просуммировать все элементы.

Comment: Ты используешь генераторы, из-за того, что скобки стоят в разных местах ответ разный. Это, считай, как в математике. Ты поставил скобки в разных местах -> дал разным действиям приоритет. Тут так же. Разберись, какой приоритет (последовательность, в которой будет идти итерация), тебе нужен, тогда поймёшь, куда скобочки ставить)

Comment: Потому что 5+7+9=21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
return [sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors)
        for i in range(num_elements)] # Здесь скобка после vectors
```

Это [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), преобразуем его в цикл:

```
r = []
for i in range(num_elements):
    r.append(sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors))
return r
```

Внутри суммы [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), преобразуем его в цикл:

```
r = []
for i in range(num_elements):
    s = 0
    for vector in vectors:
        s += vector[i]
    r.append(s)
return r
```

Второй вариант:

```
return [sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors
        for i in range(num_elements))] # Здесь скобка после num_elements
```

Это не `list comprehension`, это просто литерал - список из одного элемента:

```
s = sum(vector[i] for vector in vectors for i in range(num_elements))
return [s]
```

Внутри суммы снова `generator expression` но более сложный - два вложенных цикла:

```
s = 0
for vector in vectors:
    for i in range(num_elements):
        s += vector[i]
return [s]
```

Из этого разбора видно что в первом варианте элементов больше, сами они меньше. Во втором варианте элемент один - сумма всех значений из первого варианта.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение